# Gridview paging Show all Records

Tags: asp.net, gridview

i have a gridview that has paging enabled. i also have a dropdown on the pager of the gridview where the user can select how many records per page they would like to retrieve. Once the dropdown is changed then an event is fired (shown below) to rerun the query with the updated results per page request. This works very well. I did however want to have a value "All" on the dropdown aswell and the method i used to impliment this is by disabling paging.

This all works brilliantly except for one issue. When the user selects "All" on the dropdown i would like to still show the pager once the gridview is updated. It doesnt show because i turned off paging but is there a way to show the pager again? See my code below for the event. (As you can see i renable the pager at the end but this has no effect)

thanks
damo

**Code behind Event for Dropdown Change**

```
void GridViewMainddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //changes page size
            if ((((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue).ToString() == "All")
            {

                GridViewMain.AllowPaging = false;

            }
            else
            {
                GridViewMain.PageSize = int.Parse(((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue);

            }



            //binds data source
            Result fAuditOverallStatusLatest = new Result(sConn);
            GridViewMain.DataSource = Result.getAuditOverallStatusLatest();            
            GridViewMain.PageIndex = 0;
            GridViewMain.DataBind();
            GridViewMain.AllowPaging = true;
            GridViewMain.BottomPagerRow.Visible = true;
            GridViewMain.TopPagerRow.Visible = true;
        }
```

**DDL Code behind**

```
protected void GridViewMain_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Pager)
            {
                DropDownList GridViewMainddl = new DropDownList();
                //adds variants of pager size
                GridViewMainddl.Items.Add("5");
                GridViewMainddl.Items.Add("10");
                GridViewMainddl.Items.Add("20");
                GridViewMainddl.Items.Add("50");
                GridViewMainddl.Items.Add("100");
                GridViewMainddl.Items.Add("200");
                GridViewMainddl.Items.Add("500");
                GridViewMainddl.Items.Add("All");
                GridViewMainddl.AutoPostBack = true;
                //selects item due to the GridView current page size
                ListItem li = GridViewMainddl.Items.FindByText(GridViewMain.PageSize.ToString());
                if (li != null)
                    GridViewMainddl.SelectedIndex = GridViewMainddl.Items.IndexOf(li);
                GridViewMainddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(GridViewMainddl_SelectedIndexChanged);
                //adds dropdownlist in the additional cell to the pager table
                Table pagerTable = e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as Table;
                TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                cell.Style["padding-left"] = "15px";
                cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Page Size:"));
                cell.Controls.Add(GridViewMainddl);
                pagerTable.Rows[0].Cells.Add(cell);
                //add current Page of total page count
                TableCell cellPageNumber = new TableCell();
                cellPageNumber.Style["padding-left"] = "15px";
                cellPageNumber.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Page " + (GridViewMain.PageIndex + 1) + " of " + GridViewMain.PageCount));
                pagerTable.Rows[0].Cells.Add(cellPageNumber);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your `Page_Init`:

`GridViewMain.PreRender += new EventHandler(GridViewMain_PreRender);`

Then elsewhere in your `Page` class:

```
void GridViewMain_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pagerRow = (sender as GridView).BottomPagerRow;
    if (pagerRow != null)
    {
        pagerRow.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Then for your drop down event:

```
void GridViewMainddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyServices fServices = new FAServices(sConn);
    Result fAuditOverallStatusLatest = new Result(sConn);
    var data = Result.getAuditOverallStatusLatest();

    //changes page size
    if ((((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue).ToString() == "All")
    {
        GridViewMain.PageSize = data.Count();
    }
    else
    {
        GridViewMain.PageSize = int.Parse(((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue);
    }

    //binds data source
    GridViewMain.DataSource = data;            
    GridViewMain.PageIndex = 0;
    GridViewMain.DataBind();
    GridViewMain.AllowPaging = true;
}
```

In that PreRender event, you'll have to duplicate that code for the top pager.

Edit: To get `All` selected, make this change in GridViewMain_RowCreated:

```
if (li != null)
{
    GridViewMainddl.SelectedIndex = GridViewMainddl.Items.IndexOf(li);
}
else
{
    GridViewMainddl.SelectedIndex = GridViewMainddl.Items.Count - 1;
}
```

Comment: hi, can you replace in your answer _displayPager with True; and data.Count; with data.Count(); . They are the only 2 changes ive made so far to your code. Your code is working perfect (with my slight mods above) but the value "All" is not shown in the ddl when the page is redrawn. it always reverts to the first value in the dropdown i.e 5 in my case? (ive added my ddl code to the question above in case this helps) thanks damo

Comment: Made those edits.  Also, just add another line to add `All` to your dropdown in your code that creates the menu.

Comment: do you mean add GridViewMainddl.Items.Add("All"); at the end of the function protected void GridViewMain_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) (Function shown in the question). if so then that does not work?

Comment: Actually, it looks like you're adding All to the menu in your code.  I would set a break point in your `GridViewMain_RowCreated` code to make sure it's going through that code fine.  I can't see why `All` wouldn't be in the menu, but all your other page size options would be...

Comment: all is in the menu but its not selected. it reverts back to the first item in the dropdown menu when all is selected. When any other page size is selected it works perfect! interesting....!

Comment: if i put "All" as the first item in the dropdown it will work fine but it just doesnt look right as i have the values increasing in size on the dropdown and "All" really should be at the bottom of it...ideally

Comment: Figured out what you meant, check my edit.  It allows `All` to be at the bottom of the menu.

Comment: i found a bug! If the user selects "All" and the number of results in the page is equal to any value in the dropdown then that value is selected! i understand why this happens.. i just dont have a fix yet. Any ideas welcome.